# zip entries to android list view or recycler view

Tags: java, android, zip

I want to get zip file entries to the list view or recycler view but the all entries it show me like this

```
folder1/
folder1/folder2/
folder1/folder2/file.txt
folder1/file.txt
file.txt
```

but I want to do it show me only folder1 and file.txt and when I click to folder1 the list view data should show me folder2 and file.txt and if I click folder2 it show me only file.txt if you do not understand me : I want to create a zip editor or zip viewer like  [z archiver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.zdevs.zarchiver&hl=ar&gl=US)

Answer (score 0):

you can do a for loop
And if-else statement (if file or folder add in list , else (sub folder or sub file) do no thing

Comment: no... I can use split for this and thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).